# Php fetch data from two tables

Tags: php, cakephp

I have to edit a form where it contains datas form two tables.
one is master and another user. first the data is saved in user table 
and with that id the remaining datas get saved in master table.
Below is my edit code.What should i do to fetch the data and edit it.

```
     public function edit() {
    $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
    $this->Master->id = $id;
    if( $this->Master->exists()){
        if( $this->request->is( 'post' ) || $this->request->is( 'put' ) ){
            if( $this->Master->save( $this->request->data ) ){
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            else { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to edit row. Please, try again');
            } 
        }
        else { 
          $this->request->data = $this->Master->read();
        }
    } 
}
```

Could somebody help pls..

Comment: why you fetching the data. With user table id you can edit user fields. match user id and user_id in master table. if same then get master table id and edit master fields. This is what i understood. if i am wrong pls explain more your question.

Comment: If you got your answer what you need then i am posting my command in answer. pls confirm me

Comment: pls explain more and tell me what  output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code by :

```
$this->request->data = $this->Master->read(null, $id);

$this->set('masterArr',$this->Master->find('all',array('conditions' =>
array('Master.id ' => $id))));
```